# How to add server side validation for a unique email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have a very simple form that I use to get email addresses to send a newsletter. I am trying to figure out how I can add some server-side validation to check to see if the email address entered is already in my `database`. Then if it has been entered already, it doesn't allow the form to submit and it throws an error that the user can see.

How would I go about checking for this and showing the error?

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="newsletter-form">
    <input type="email" id="footer-grid1-newsletter-input" placeholder="Your Email Address" pattern=".{3,}" required>
    <input type="submit" id="footer-grid1-newsletter-submit" name="submit" value='&nbsp'>
</form>


 $("#newsletter-form").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var newsletter_email = $("#footer-grid1-newsletter-input").val();
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');

        $.ajax({ 
            url: "newsletterSend.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "newsletter_email": newsletter_email
            },
            success: function (data) {
            //  console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
                if (data == "Error!") {
                    alert("Unable to insert email!");
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    $("#newsletter-form")[0].reset();
                    $('.newsletter-popup').fadeIn(350).delay(2000).fadeOut();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
                //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
            }
        });
    });

$newsletter_email = $_POST['newsletter_email'];

try {

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO newsletter (email, subscribed) VALUES (?, NOW())");
        if ( false===$stmt ) {
            die('Newsletter email prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
        }
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $newsletter_email);
        if ( false===$stmt ) {
            die('Newsletter email bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }
    $stmt->execute();
        if ( false===$stmt ) {
            die('Newsletter email execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }
```

Comment: Just add return false; in your ajax  error query and it wont submit

Comment: @AslanKaya How would that check if the email has already been entered, though?

Comment: You will need to perform SQL check if the email already available before you try to insert. example below should help.

Comment: Try below example hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This below should help you out.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //newly added  
    $('#footer-grid1-newsletter-submit').click(function() {      
        var emailVal = $('#footer-grid1-newsletter-input').val(); // assuming this is a input text field       
        $.post('checkemail.php', {'email' : emailVal}, function(data) {
            if(data=='exist'){
                $('#alert').html("<p> You are already subscribed to our website</p>");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#newsletter-form').submit();
            }
        });     
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="newsletter-form">
    <input type="email" id="footer-grid1-newsletter-input" placeholder="Your Email Address" pattern=".{3,}" required>
    <input type="submit" id="footer-grid1-newsletter-submit" name="submit" value='&nbsp'>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


$sql = "SELECT email FROM newsletter WHERE email = '" .$_POST['email'] ."'";
$select = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);

if (mysqli_num_rows > 0) {
    echo "exist";
}
else {
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO newsletter (email, subscribed) VALUES (?, NOW())");  
}
```

Comment: This makes the form reload the page.

Comment: ... Don't answer with vulnerabilities such as SQL injection, please. Even with an example.

Comment: Can you try alert(data); and see what the output is. return false; should disable the form submit unless the php code is not sending result exist Also this is example result you should consider your own aproach for security such as Duncan mentioned. you can use mysql_real_escape_string() to void any SQL injections.